# How can I add a month to a certain part of my output?

Tags: c++, arrays

OK so for my assignment I have to display average rainfall and the months associated with them. This is what the output should look like.

```
  The year's average monthly rainfall was 139 mm.
September has the highest rainfall (190 mm).
January has the lowes rainfall (95 mm)

Month    Rainfall(mm)   Classification
1                  95                     Dry
2               100                     Dry
3               120                 Average
4               130                Average
5               135                Average
6               145                Average
7               155                Average
8               185                 Rainy
9               190                 Rainy
10             160              Average
11             130              Average
12             120             Average
```

This is what mine actually looks like.

```
The year's average monthly rainfall was 139mm
The lowest rainfall was (95 mm)
The highest rainfall was (190 mm)

Months     Rainfall(mm)     Classification

1          95               Dry         
2          100              Dry         
3          120              Average     
4          130              Average     
5          135              Average     
6          145              Average     
7          155              Average     
8          185              Rainy       
9          190              Rainy       
10         160              Average     
11         130              Average     
12         120              Average
```

So yeah I got it working like I want to except for one part.

My output has this

The lowest rainfall was (95 mm)

The highest rainfall was (190 mm)

I want it to show the months the measurements are associated with like in the intended output but I don't know exactly how to do that. Any ideas on how? Here's the part of my code associated with it. I also edited the code so that it'll work by itself.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include<fstream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{

int months[12] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 };
int rainFall;
string Classification[12];

ifstream inputFile;
inputFile.open("rainfall.txt");

int n=0;
int sum=0,total=0;


fstream file("rainfall.txt");
while(file >> n)
{
    sum += n;
    total++;
}


int average = (float) sum/total;


if( (average + 0.5) >= (int(average) + 1) )
{
cout << "The year's average monthly rainfall was " << average << "mm" << endl;

}
else
{
cout << "The year's average monthly rainfall was " << average+1 << "mm" << endl;
}

{
    int low = numeric_limits<int>::max();
    int high = numeric_limits<int>::min(); 
    ifstream fin("rainfall.txt");


    if(!fin)
        return 1;

    int n;
    while(fin >> n)
    {
        if(n > high)
            high = n;
        if(n < low)
            low = n;
    }

    cout << "The lowest rainfall was (" << low << " mm)" << '\n';
    cout << "The highest rainfall was (" << high << " mm)" << '\n';
}
}
```

Sorry if what I'm trying to ask is hard to understand. The contents of the txt file are just the numbers under Rainfall in the output.

Comment: You could add a counter, then have an array with the month names and when you set high/low, you can also set highMonth, lowMonth.

Comment: how is the file you are reading... you need to associate it in some way to each month.

Answer (score 1):

assuming the file is this format:

133
231
90
...
where first number is jaunary and last is december... you just need to add this:

```
int low = numeric_limits<int>::max();
int high = numeric_limits<int>::min(); 
ifstream fin("rainfall.txt");


if(!fin)
    return 1;

int n;

int monthCounter = 0;
int monthHigh;
int monthLow;

while(fin >> n)
{
    monthCounter++;

    if(n > high) {
        high = n;
        monthHigh = monthCounter;
    }
    if(n < low) {
        monthLow = monthCounter;
        low = n;
    }
}

cout << "The lowest rainfall was (" << low << " mm)" << '\n';
cout << "The highest rainfall was (" << high << " mm)" << '\n';
```

At the end of the code you will have the month in monthHigh and monthLow just add an array with month names and then you index it with monthHigh and monthLow.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of string with the names of the months, and use the month integer to index into it. You have an array called "months", but are not using it anywhere in the code, see where you need to read the month from the file and do it.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is with a container, preferably a [`vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). You should read into the container once then use that instead of reopening the file over and over. You can slurp into the container like this:

```
ifstream fin("rainfall.txt");
const vector<int> vec{ istream_iterator<int>(fin), istream_iterator<int>() };
```

Now you can use [`accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) to do your average and [`minmax_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element) to find your min and max:

```
cout << "The year's average monthly rainfall was " << accumulate(cbegin(vec), cend(vec), 0.0) / size(vec) << endl;

const auto its = minmax_element(cbegin(vec), cend(vec));

cout << distance(cbegin(vec), its.first) + 1 << " has the highest rainfall (" << *its.first << "mm)\n" << distance(cbegin(vec), its.second) + 1 << " has the lowest rainfall (" << *its.second << "mm)\n";
```

You can even simplify your table:

```
cout << "Month    Rainfall(mm)   Classification\n" << left;

for(auto i = 0; i < size(vec); ++i) {
    if(vec[i] <= 100) {
        cout << setw(9) << i + 1 << setw(15) << vec[i] << "Dry\n";
    } else if(vec[i] <= 159) {
        cout << setw(9) << i + 1 << setw(15) << vec[i] << "Average\n";
    } else {
        cout << setw(9) << i + 1 << setw(15) << vec[i] << "Rainy\n";
    }
}
```

I've written a live example with a little fancier formatting here: http://ideone.com/QQZBoM